# using tryCatch to manage zero variance variables in R

Tags: r, data-management

I need to use `cor` function inside a for-loop and it stops with this error:

> Error: from glmnet Fortran code (error code 7777); All used predictors
> have zero variance

Although throwing data away is an option when dealing with constant predictors across samples, I am looking for managing this so that in such cases, zero is assigned. So,I want use `tryCatch` . Here is the structure of two datasets that I use as 'x' and 'y' for `cor` function:

```
my_list <- list(ENSG0000014 = list(set_1 = structure(list(expr = c(" 9.940670e-02", 
" 1.289670e-01", "-7.394904e-03", " 9.940670e-02", " 9.940670e-02"
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)), set_2 = structure(list(expr = c(" 9.940670e-02", " 1.289670e-01", 
"-7.394904e-03", " 9.940670e-02", " 9.940670e-02")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), set_3 = structure(list(
    expr = c(" 9.940670e-02", " 1.289670e-01", "-7.394904e-03", 
    " 9.940670e-02", " 9.940670e-02")), row.names = c(NA, -5L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))), ENSG0000015 = list(
    set_1 = structure(list(expr = c(" 9.940670e-02", " 1.289670e-01", 
    "-7.394904e-03", " 9.940670e-02", " 9.940670e-02")), row.names = c(NA, 
    -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), set_2 = structure(list(
        expr = c(" 9.940670e-02", " 1.289670e-01", "-7.394904e-03", 
        " 9.940670e-02", " 9.940670e-02")), row.names = c(NA, 
    -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), set_3 = structure(list(
        expr = c(" 9.940670e-02", " 1.289670e-01", "-7.394904e-03", 
        " 9.940670e-02", " 9.940670e-02")), row.names = c(NA, 
    -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))))

# class(my_list[[1]][[1]])
# [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

alpha0 <- structure(list(s1 = c(0.0187340226414619, 0.00908524361272445, 
0.00931968564730621, 0.0112482521491358, 0.00929048221018, 0.0126019919679288, 
0.0194020980563262, 0.00510680509885104, 0.0182302538181811, 
0.0070983818621192, 0.0111253617983923, 0.00820051118160036, 
0.0221411777890218, 0.0120777292746757, 0.00681949654210974, 
0.0119405765039798, 0.00730874406889384, 0.0194020980563262, 
0.00838540350315828), s1.1 = c(-0.0111797117112052, -0.0151154469367662, 
-0.0274839538246719, -0.0232526535738252, -0.0214438607379155, 
-0.0139148593878817, -0.0233534584833798, -0.0149056307836724, 
-0.014480345769519, -0.0180705053683703, -0.0226853642294842, 
-0.0189920966797582, -0.00967108125788073, -0.0254219105164431, 
-0.0217286557382764, -0.0151528980623231, -0.0176955630367825, 
-0.0178792733665001, -0.0229882892112302), s1.2 = c(-0.00657906147914681, 
-0.00161418712964399, 0.00549018150634929, -0.00563876737503981, 
0.00676109674439662, 0.0175951004499502, 0.000870549311249299, 
-0.00253963535899881, 0.00402394916896305, 0.00305742983988951, 
-0.00272125028295169, 0.00263511211988609, -0.00287396022316179, 
-0.000843642468373697, 0.00780145969696268, 0.00971427253061111, 
0.00155452869320207, 0.00897302942313759, 0.0000166335321619695
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 19L))
```

And here is what I tied with no success.

```
for (g in 1:2) { 
  for (f in 1:3) {
    ## correlation between actual expression value (testing set) and the predicted one.
    cor_r_sets[[f]] <- cor(my_list[[g]][[f]], 
                            alpha0[, f])
  }
  cor_r_genes[[g]] <- cor_r_sets
}

## Usigy tryCatch:

for (g in 1:2) { 
  for (f in 1:3) {
    ## tryatch to evaluate the zero variances and assign the exceptions.
cor_rg <- tryCatch(
  {
    cor_r_sets[[f]] <- cor(final_lists$expr.y[[g]][[f]], 
                           alpha0.predicted_final[, f]

     },
      error = function(e) {
        cor_r_sets[[f]] = 0
      }
    )

  }
      }
      cor_r_genes[[g]] <- cor_r_sets
    }
```

Could you please guide me how to make it work!

Comment: if you want to work with the error function in tryCatch you need to `return()` the values from within the error function

Comment: also your test data does not work with your code. my_list is character and has only 5 entries while alpha0 columns have 19 rows

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you need to return a value for the error. Also, you data doesn't work as posted, so I `type.convert` the data to numeric and then I only use the first 5 rows in alpha0.

```r
cor_r_sets <- c()
cor_r_genes <- list()

for (g in 1:2) { 
  for (f in 1:3) {
   
    cor_r_sets[[f]] <- tryCatch(
      cor(
        type.convert(my_list[[g]][[f]], as.is = T),
        alpha0[1:5, f]),
      error = \(e) 0)
  }
  cor_r_genes[[g]] <- cor_r_sets
}

cor_r_genes
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#>           [,1]
#> expr 0.1893385
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]]
#>           [,1]
#> expr 0.7048062
#> 
#> [[1]][[3]]
#>            [,1]
#> expr -0.5055223
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]][[1]]
#>           [,1]
#> expr 0.1893385
#> 
#> [[2]][[2]]
#>           [,1]
#> expr 0.7048062
#> 
#> [[2]][[3]]
#>            [,1]
#> expr -0.5055223
```

I would recommend looking into `map` functions to avoid using loops. For this example it is relatively fast to use a loop, but indexing can be confusing as loops become nested and can quickly become slow. Example of mapping:

```r
library(tidyverse)

map(my_list,
    \(x) map2(
      x, 1:3, 
      \(x, y) tryCatch(
        cor(
          type.convert(x[,1], as.is = T), 
          alpha0[1:5,y]
          ), 
        error = \(e) 0
        )
      )
    )
#> $ENSG0000014
#> $ENSG0000014$set_1
#>           [,1]
#> expr 0.1893385
#> 
#> $ENSG0000014$set_2
#>           [,1]
#> expr 0.7048062
#> 
#> $ENSG0000014$set_3
#>            [,1]
#> expr -0.5055223
#> 
#> 
#> $ENSG0000015
#> $ENSG0000015$set_1
#>           [,1]
#> expr 0.1893385
#> 
#> $ENSG0000015$set_2
#>           [,1]
#> expr 0.7048062
#> 
#> $ENSG0000015$set_3
#>            [,1]
#> expr -0.5055223
```

Comment: thanks. regarding the first solution, what does the bachslash? When I try to run, there is a syntax message about unxpected bachslash '\' and expected comma ',' after expression.

Comment: This is the first time I try to use tryCatch but in the syntax there are curly brackets separating expression and error sections that you did not use them. Could you please explain also this part.

Comment: The `\(e)` is shorthand for the anonymous function `function(e)`. You may need to update R to use this new functionality or replace with `function(e)`.

Comment: You only need to use curly brackets when your expression is multi-part. For example: `tryCatch({a <- "k"; a + 5 }, error = function(e) "Not a number")`. Otherwise you do not need them: `tryCatch("k"+ 5, error =function(e) "Not a number")` .